# Apache do not show README.TXT files in directory listing. How can i enable it?

Tags: apache, http, centos

In CentOS 6.0, i have apache for allowing to download drivers + one README.TXT file. But when the site is visited as `http://site.mooo.com/`  it shows all zip files but not the TXT file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site.mooo.com
 ServerAlias site.mooo.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/download
 <Directory /var/www/html/download>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Should show all, but only shows two zip file

```
/var/www/html/download/
driver.zip
driver.new.zip
README.TXT
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

create a .htaccess, try `Options +Indexes`

Comment: Why does it only exclude README files?

Comment: add `Options +Indexes` in the .htaccess file does not make it visible.

Comment: @vee This is 8 years ago, I forgot what the question was and what my answer was. My answer was accepted, I must've said something that solved the problem of the OP, that's all that matters, helping OP, that reason alone should make my answer immune from downvotes. it was the only answer for a year and it was accepted, it means I helped someone when he needed help, not after a year from needing help.

Answer (score 34):

I know it's old, but for what it's worth :

- Edit your httpd.conf file
- Locate the line with the *IndexIgnore* directive
- Remove `README*` from that pattern

=> It will display the `README.txt` files.

Comment: Or for Xampp: `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf`

Comment: This actually appears be the correct answer for the question. Suggest changing the officially accepted answer to this.

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: How do I do this without access to the file?

Comment: Due to the auto index is working with readme.html file. The readme.html file will be added to the bottom of directory listing page (if exists) before end of `</body>` tag. So, it is recommended to change from `README*` to `README.html` instead.

Comment: In httpd (apache2) the README is in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf`