# EasyPHP doesn't show README.md in indexes

Tags: easyphp, easyphp-devserver

I'm using EasyPHP Devserver 17 and have cloned a GitHub repo to a directory in my `eds-www` folder. When I navigate to the directory index of `localhost/path/to/repo/` in my browser, I can see all the files, *except* `README.md`. EasyPHP will list other markdown files in the index, too.

I tried the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11991421/5025767, but when I access my `http.conf` file, there is no indexignore option for `README*`.

How do I make EasyPHP display `README.md`?

Answer (score 0):

EasyPHP's setting to show README files is located in `C:\<path to server root>\conf\extra\httpd-autoindex.conf`.

Editing this file, removing `README*` from the `IndexIgnore` directive, and then restarting the server, shows README files in the directory listing.